# Count rows that have timestamps within past hour of that row

Tags: mysql, datetime

Trying to find a way to count rows together without grouping them. Because if I group per hour like hour(date) then it just shrinks the result down. Instead I wish to count the row and add any rows to that count that are within the past hour of that row.

#### Data:

```
date
-------------------
2017-11-01 03:43:00
2017-11-01 03:45:00
2017-11-04 14:14:00
2017-11-04 15:01:00
2017-11-04 15:08:00
2017-11-04 15:12:00
2017-11-04 15:16:00
```

#### Result:

```
date                    count
-------------------     -------------------
2017-11-01 03:43:00     1
2017-11-01 03:45:00     2
2017-11-04 14:14:00     1
2017-11-04 15:01:00     2
2017-11-04 15:08:00     3
2017-11-04 15:12:00     4
2017-11-04 15:16:00     3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use a "correlated subquery"

```
select
   `date` 
  , (select count(*) from yourtable t2
     where t2.`date`>= date_sub(t1.`date - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) and t2.`date` <= t1.`date`
    ) as `count`
from yourtable t1
```

note, if you want to *strictly* count rows "in the past" use `less than`, not `less than or equal` in the query.